# how to make mutating func in enum with different return value

Tags: swift

a piece of code in an enum  (deck of cards, they should have a 'status' either true or false)

```
enum Card:Int
{

case zero = 0, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine

init()
{
    self = .zero
}

init?(digit: Int)
{
    switch digit
    {
    case 0: self = .zero case 1: self = .one case 2: self = .two
    case 3: self = .three case 4: self = .four case 5: self = .five
    case 6: self = .six case 7: self = .seven case 8: self = .eight
    case 9: self = .nine
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
 var status
 {
    get
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .zero: return false
            case .one: return false
            case .two: return false
            case .three: return false
            case .four: return false
            case .five: return false
            case .six: return false
            case .seven: return false
            case .eight: return false
            case .nine: return false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a mutating function here that will change their value to true when function runs

```
mutating func swap() {
    switch status {
        case TRUE:
            self = false
        case false:
            self = TRUE

        }
    }
}
```

code above doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**create a structure called Cards** which has **two stored properties** one of **Card enum** type and another of **Bool type to keep track of status** here you can declare a function swap() which changes the status value:

```
  struct Cards {
  let card:Card?   //This property stores an instance of Card enum 
  var status = true
     mutating func swap()
    {
        self.status = !self.status
    }
    init(cardDigit: Int)
    {
        self.card = Card(digit: cardDigit)
    }
    init()
    {
        self.card = Card()
    }
 }

  var aCard :Cards = Cards(cardDigit: 2)
  aCard.status // returns true
  aCard.swap()
  aCard.status //returns false
```

You can remove the status computed property from enum, because we can access it from structure.

Comment: "enum case pattern cant match values of non-enum type 'Bool'

Comment: I have changed the code as per your requirement and here no need to use status computed property in your Card enum

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use structs, another approach could be returning a new instance of the enum

```
func swap(status: Bool) -> Card {
    var card = Card()
    switch status {
        case true:
            card.status = false
        case false:
            card.status = true
    }
    return card
}
```